# What's wrong with mt_rand in PHP?

Tags: php

I tried to make a simple name generator. Help me to identify why it's not working. I think it's because of mt_rand function. Sorry if question seems banal or irrelevant, I'm first time here and new to programming. Here's the code:

```
<?php
    echo 'Ovo je moja verzija Polumenta generatora';
    $prvo = 'bcdfghtnjpknmlrjdzdjs';
    $drugo = 'aeiou';
    $trece = 'bcdfghtnjpknmlrjsdzdj';
    $cetvrto = 'uo';
    $prvos = mt_rand($prvo[0],$prvo[17]);
    $drugos = mt_rand($drugo[0],$drugo[4]);
    $treces = mt_rand($trece[0],$trece[17]);
    $cetvrtos = mt_rand($cetvrto[0],$cetvrto[1]);
        echo $prvos.$drugos.$treces.$cetvrtos.' Polumenta'

?>
```

Comment: What is not working ? Can you please explain the problem or error ?

Comment: From where you are getting these values:- $prvo[0],$prvo[17],$drugo[0],$drugo[4],$trece[0],$trece[17],$cetvrto[0],$cetvrto[1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mt_rand takes integers as arguments and returns an integer. You are trying to pass it characters and return characters. You should do something like:

```
<?php
  echo 'Ovo je moja verzija Polumenta generatora';
  $prvo = 'bcdfghtnjpknmlrjdzdjs';
  $drugo = 'aeiou';
  $trece = 'bcdfghtnjpknmlrjsdzdj';
  $cetvrto = 'uo';
  $prvos = $prvo[mt_rand(0,strlen($prvo) - 1)];
  $drugos = $drugo[mt_rand(0,strlen($drugo) - 1)];
  $treces = $trece[mt_rand(0,strlen($trece) - 1)];
  $cetvrtos = $cetvrto[mt_rand(0,strlen($cetvrto) - 1)];
  echo $prvos.$drugos.$treces.$cetvrtos.' Polumenta'
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it in another way, using arrays and rand() function.

```
$chrs[0] = str_split('bcdfghtnjpknmlrjdzdjs'); // array of consonants
$chrs[1] = str_split('aeiou'); // array of vowels
$length = 8; // nick name length
```

Than generate random sequence of chars any length

```
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
{
 $v_or_c = rand(0,1);
 if($v_or_c)
 {
  $nick_name .= $chrs[$v_or_c][rand(0, sizeof($chrs[$v_or_c]))];
 }
 else
 {
  $nick_name .= $chrs[$v_or_c][rand(0, sizeof($chrs[$v_or_c]))];
 }
}
echo ucfirst($nick_name); // ucfirst - to upper case first letter
```